# How to get my "player" to move after answering the dialog box?

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, maze

I'm using Python 3 and have very, very little experience with Python, so please be kind in your answers. I'm trying to make a maze game for a project but the maze game is also a vocabulary game! When the player rolls over a "treasure" then a question pops up.
I got a dialog box to pop up when the player rolls over it, but after answering the question, the player stops moving!

Here is the section where I open a file with vocabulary words and generate a random word for the dialog box:

```
# Game loop in regards to the gold.
def gold_encounter():
    # Check for player collision with a question.
    # Iterate through the questions list.
    for question in questions:
        if player.collision(question):
            infile = open("translations.txt", "r")
            line = infile.readlines()
            ques = line[random.randrange(0, 25)]
            answer = simpledialog.askstring("Input", ques, parent=root)
            # Destroy the question.
            question.destroy()
            # Remove question from questions list.
            questions.remove(question)
```

I don't know what to do about this problem, but I've done some research and cannot find an answer to my problem. Below, I've provided my full game code so everyone can see the context in which this code sits. Please let me know the problem and show me how I can fix it, it would be much appreciated.

```
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen
import tkinter
from tkinter import PhotoImage, simpledialog
import random

largefont = ("Verdana", 12)

# Define function to create Spanish level.
def span():
    pen.setup(level_1)
    player.setup(level_1)
    setup(level_1)

# Define function to create French level.
def fren():
    pen.setup(level_2)
    player.setup(level_2)
    setup(level_2)

# Define function to create Japanese level.
def jpn():
    pen.setup(level_3)
    player.setup(level_3)
    setup(level_3)

# Define function to create Turkish level.
def turk():
    pen.setup(level_4)
    player.setup(level_4)
    setup(level_4)

# Create window and canvas using tkinter.
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Language Labyrinth")

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=600, height=600)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.bgcolor('black')

# Define a function to set flag background for Spanish level
def spanishFlag():
    screen.bgpic("spainflag.png")

# Define a function to set flag background for French level
def frenchFlag():
    screen.bgpic("franceflaggrunge.png")

# Define a function to set flag background for Japanese level        
def japaneseFlag():
    screen.bgpic("japanflagoffwhite.png")

# Define a function to set flag background for Turkish level
def turkishFlag():
    screen.bgpic("turkishflagdiagonal.png")

# Define a function to combine the level and background setup functions for Spanish level
def combinedSpanishCommands():
    span()
    spanishFlag()

# Define a function to combine the level and background setup functions for French level
def combinedFrenchCommands():
    fren()
    frenchFlag()

# Define a function to combine the level and background setup functions for Japanese level
def combinedJapaneseCommands():
    jpn()
    japaneseFlag()

# Define a function to combine the level and background setup functions for Turkish level
def combinedTurkishCommands():
    turk()
    turkishFlag()

# Create class with separate window to choose level.
class StartPage():
    def __init__(self):
        # Creation of second window.
        wn = tkinter.Tk()
        wn.title("Welcome!")
        # Creation of game title on start page.
        label = tkinter.Label(wn, text="Language Labyrinth", font=largefont)
        label.pack()

        # Create Spanish level button.
        button = tkinter.Button(wn, text="Spanish", command= combinedSpanishCommands)
        button.pack()

        # Create French level button.
        button2 = tkinter.Button(wn, text="French", command= combinedFrenchCommands)
        button2.pack()

        # Create Japanese level button.
        button3 = tkinter.Button(wn, text="Japanese", command= combinedJapaneseCommands)
        button3.pack()

        # Create Turkish level button.
        button4 = tkinter.Button(wn, text="Turkish", command= combinedTurkishCommands)
        button4.pack()

        # Create quit button for start page.
        qbutton = tkinter.Button(wn, text="Quit", command=wn.destroy)
        qbutton.pack()

start = StartPage()

# Create Pen class to draw the maze.
class Pen(RawTurtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(screen, shape='square')
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('white')
        self.penup()

    # Create setup so the maze will be drawn.
    def setup(self, level):
        for y in range(len(level)):
            screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

            for x in range(len(level[y])):
                if level[y][x] == 'X':
                    screen_x = (x * 24) - 288

                    self.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
                    self.stamp()

                    walls.append((screen_x, screen_y))

# Create player class to have a player.
class Player(RawTurtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(screen, shape='square')
        self.penup()
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('black')

    def bKey(self):
        global color
        print("b key pressed")
        self.color('blue')

    def rKey(self):
        global color
        print("r key pressed")
        self.color('red')

    def gKey(self):
        global color
        print("g key pressed")
        self.color('green')

    def pKey(self):
        global color
        print("p key pressed")
        self.color('purple')

    def yKey(self):
        global color
        print("y key pressed")
        self.color('goldenrod')

    def oKey(self):
        global color
        print("o key pressed")
        self.color('orange')

    # Create setup to create the player on the screen.
    def setup(self, level):
        for y in range(len(level)):
            for x in range(len(level[y])):
                if level[y][x] == 'P':
                    screen_x = (x * 24) - 288
                    screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

                    self.goto(screen_x, screen_y)

                    return

    # Define a function that will allow player to move up.
    def move_up(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor()
        movetoY = self.ycor() + 24

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Define a function that will allow player to move down.
    def move_down(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor()
        movetoY = self.ycor() - 24

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Define a function that will allow player to move left.
    def move_left(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor() - 24
        movetoY = self.ycor()

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Define a function that will allow player to move right.
    def move_right(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor() + 24
        movetoY = self.ycor()

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Check if player touches the question.
    def collision(self, other):
        return self.distance(other) < 5

# Create Question class to create the "gold" in the game.
class Question(RawTurtle):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(screen, shape='circle', visible=False)
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('hotpink')
        self.penup()
        self.goto(x, y)
        self.showturtle()

    # Define function that will remove gold when collided with.
    def destroy(self):
        self.hideturtle()

# Define function to setup the "gold" in the game.
def setup(level):
    for y in range(len(level)):
        for x in range(len(level[y])):
            char = level[y][x]

            screen_x = -288 + (x * 24)
            screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

            if char == 'Q':
                questions.append(Question(screen_x, screen_y))

# Define a function for the quit button.
def quitPlaying():
    root.destroy()
    root.quit()

# Game loop in regards to the gold.
def gold_encounter():
    # Check for player collision with a question.
    # Iterate through the questions list.
    for question in questions:
        if player.collision(question):
            infile = open("translations.txt", "r")
            line = infile.readlines()
            ques = line[random.randrange(0, 25)]
            answer = simpledialog.askstring("Input", ques, parent=root)
            # Destroy the question.
            question.destroy()
            # Remove question from questions list.
            questions.remove(question)

# Create frame where button(s) will be.
frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

# Add questions list.
questions = []

# Wall coordinate list.
walls = []

# Create a levels list.
levels = []

# Define first level.
level_1 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XP XXXXXXX          XXXXX",
"X  XXXXXXX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"X       XX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"X       XX  XXX        XX",
"XXXXXX  XX  XXX   Q    XX",
"XXXXXX  XX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XXXXXX  XX    XXXX  XXXXX",
"X  XXX Q      XXXX  XXXXX",
"X  XXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X     Q          XXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXX  X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX  X",
"XXX  XXXXXXXXXX         X",
"XXX               Q     X",
"XXX         XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX              X",
"XX   XXXXX        Q     X",
"XX   XXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XX    XXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XX    Q     XXXX        X",
"XXXX                    X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Define second level.
level_2 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XP  XX       XX      XXXX",
"X   XX       XX      XXXX",
"X   XXXXXXX  XX  XX     X",
"X   XXXXXXX  XX  XX Q   X",
"X   XX   XX  XX  XXXXX  X",
"X   XX   XX  XX  XXXXX  X",
"XQ         Q     XX  X  X",
"X                XX  X  X",
"X   XXXXXXX   XXXXX  XXXX",
"X   XX   XX             X",
"XXXXXX   XX        Q    X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXX   X",
"X      Q      XX   XX   X",
"X             XX   XX   X",
"XXXXXXXXXX    XX        X",
"XXXXXX   X    XX     Q  X",
"XXXXXX   X    XX   XX   X",
"X                 X  X  X",
"X       Q         X  X  X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXX  X  X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXX     X",
"X         X             X",
"X         XQ     XXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Define third level.
level_3 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X      X   XP           X",
"X    Q X   X            X",
"X   XXXX   XXXXXXXXXX   X",
"X   XXXX   XXXXXXXXXX   X",
"X         Q    XX       X",
"X              XX       X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXX   XXX",
"X              XXXX   XXX",
"X              XXXX   XXX",
"XXXXX Q XXXXXXXXXXX   XXX",
"X                   Q   X",
"X                       X",
"XXXXXXXXXX Q  XXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   X",
"XXXX         XXXXXXXXX  X",
"XXX      XXXXXXXXX      X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXX   X",
"X            X      Q   X",
"X  Q         X       XXXX",
"XXXXXXX            XXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXXX Q XXXXXXXXXX",
"X                       X",
"X Q         XXX       Q X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Define fourth level.
level_4 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX  P  XXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXX Q XXXXXXXXXXX",
"X                       X",
"X          XXX          X",
"XXXXX  Q  XXXXX  Q  XXXXX",
"X          XXX          X",
"XXXXXXXX    X    XXXXXXXX",
"X Q         X         Q X",
"X           X           X",
"XXXXXXXXXX QXQ XXXXXXXXXX",
"X                       X",
"X                       X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXX      X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXX Q  XXXXX",
"XQ                      X",
"X                       X",
"XXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXXXX      XXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXX  Q XXXXXXXXXXX Q  X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Add the level(s) to the levels list.
levels.append(level_1)
levels.append(level_2)
levels.append(level_3)
levels.append(level_4)

# Class instances.
pen = Pen()
player = Player()

# Creation of quit button.
quitButton = tkinter.Button(frame, text='Quit', command=quitPlaying)
quitButton.pack()

# Button commands for player movement
screen.onkeypress(player.move_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(player.move_down, 'Down')
screen.onkeypress(player.move_left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(player.move_right, 'Right')

# Button commands for customizable player colors 
screen.onkeypress(player.bKey, "b")
screen.onkeypress(player.rKey, "r")
screen.onkeypress(player.gKey, "g")
screen.onkeypress(player.pKey, "p")
screen.onkeypress(player.yKey, "y")
screen.onkeypress(player.oKey, "o")

screen.listen()

# Call main game loop.
screen.mainloop()
```

So basically, after the player answers the dialog box, I expect the player to still be able to move. But it just stays still and the buttons no longer work.
I apologize for my lack of knowledge. Please explain as simply as possible. Thank you in advance for any and all advice!

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see if you get error message ? If you get error then show full error in question (not in comment)

Comment: How do I do that? I just run it normally and I don't get any errors in the shell. How else do I run it?

Comment: I mean `python script.py`. But I see you have solution below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

interesting game, i played around with your code and found out player stop move after answering the question and the reason is screen lose its listen functionality, you should add `screen.listen()` at the end of your `gold_encounter` function:

```
def gold_encounter():
    # Check for player collision with a question.
    # Iterate through the questions list.
    for question in questions:
        if player.collision(question):
            infile = open("translations.txt", "r")
            line = infile.readlines()
            ques = line[random.randrange(0, 25)]
            answer = simpledialog.askstring("Input", ques, parent=root)
            # Destroy the question.
            question.destroy()
            # Remove question from questions list.
            questions.remove(question)
            screen.listen()  # add it here
```

after i did this it works and player moves again,

good luck with your game